# cyilnder fitting through 2d cross sections

Tags: python, curve-fitting, point-clouds, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to develop a python code that reconstructs 3D geometric primitives from point cloud. I am starting with cylinders. I should process by slicing. So now I have a set of 2D cross-sections. I have fitted circles to the extracted contours. But I don't konw how to fit a cylinder that passes through the cicles I have. Could anyone help me please. 
PS: I'm a beginner on Python 
thx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U3tW.png)

Comment: Are you restricted in the direction of your slicing? If not, slice along the long cylinder axis to get a rectangle from which you can extract the start and end points of the cylinder.

Comment: thx for your reply. Yes, in fact, I am restricted in the direction but I can extract the heigh of my cylinder.

Comment: you can determine one endpoint by slicing until you see no more circle, then you know you are past the end. Using divide-and-conquer you could determine the endpoint to a accuracy of 1/2^N using N cross sections. Now with the height, endpoint, radius of circles and axis position you know everything there is to know about the cylinder.

Comment: could you explain more about how to find the endpoint ? and how to find the axis position also . thx alot

Comment: you can keep moving the position of your slice until at some point the slice does not slice thru the cylinder; then you know you are past the end of the cylinder. If you then move back in the other direction until you hit the cylinder again you can find the approximate location of the end of the cylinder.

Comment: Checkout this could be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by fitting a line to the centers of the fitted circles. this represents the axis of my cylinder and I have the raduis that is the mean value of the raduis of cross-section cercles. Still I need to find the exact heigh of my cylinde.

```
fit_data = []
Rad = []
##

for i in range (len(C)):

    data= C[i][0]
    xc,yc,r,s = cf.least_squares_circle(data)
    fit_data.append([xc,yc,data[0,2]])
    Rad.append(r)
    cf.plot_data_circle(data[:,0], data[:,1],xc,yc,r)
fit_data=np.array(fit_data) 
print(fit_data,"\n radius =", Rad)
Center = np.mean(fit_data, axis=0)

R = np.mean(Rad)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 120)
ax.set_ylim3d(0,120)
ax.set_zlim3d(0,120)
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(m.vectors, facecolors='y', linewidths=1, alpha=0.2))
ax.scatter(fit_data[:,0], fit_data[:,1], fit_data[:,2], c='blue')
ax.scatter(verts[:,0], verts[:,1], verts[:,2], c='y')


datamean = fit_data.mean(axis=0)

# Do an SVD on the mean-centered data.
uu, dd, vv = np.linalg.svd(fit_data - datamean)

# Now vv[0] contains the first principal component, i.e. the direction
# vector of the 'best fit' line in the least squares sense.

# Now generate some points along this best fit line, for plotting.


linepts = vv[0] * np.mgrid[-60:60:2j][:, np.newaxis]

# shift by the mean to get the line in the right place
linepts += datamean
ax.plot(linepts[:,0], linepts[:,1], linepts[:,2], 'r', label = 'fitted axis')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.legend()

plt.show()

print ("Mean Radius=", R , "\n Center = " , Center)
```